# Create/Update Polygon Divisions from Border Geometry

Tags: python, parcel

Is there a method to create and update polygons (parcels?) from attribute definitions (legal definitions)?

For example, polygon X is defined as the inner geometry bounded by county line A, river B, highway C, interstate D, and county line E.

But say in a year the definition changes from river B to river F which is a nearby and roughly parallel river. Polygon X should update to include the new area but Polygon Y (on the other side of River B) should lose the area between rivers B and F.

I can, of course, create and update these polygons manually, but I'm curious to know if there is a utility, method, or process already in existence to perform this function. For example, if I create a higher resolution river feature class and want to automatically update all of the affected polygons.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any direct methods that already exist.  What might work is creating a kind of meta-definition that stores the relationships between the features that make up the polygons.  That way when one needed to be updated, the one relationship would be changed and then the polygon re-derived. Sorry that it's not specific, it's just a general thought and I don't have enough rep to put it in a comment.